# iOS crashes in TestFlight release

Tags: ios, xamarin, crash, urhosharp

Locally this does not happen but only in my test flight release. I have tried replicating this but to no avail,

[image: Here is the part of the error message]

I've been working on this for 3 days now, I am going nowhere.

[Here is the Complete Log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCG6m6zEGacdzRSpLK6HqlPgXGr2HlaN/view?usp=sharing)

Edit:
What does this mean?

[FB Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVCpJ.png)

Comment: Are you sure you changed the `aps-environment` to `production` for APNS push notification? Also, check the Entitlements out just in case you missed something https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/entitlements?tabs=windows

Comment: I don't have my Push Notifications enabled would that be a problem for the app?

Comment: It depends do you have any use of push notifications? More than 90% of mobile apps do so i assumed even yours did!

Comment: Sir can you take at a look at my edit

Comment: Your complete logs don't have public access!

Comment: Oh sorry forgot about that here is the link :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCG6m6zEGacdzRSpLK6HqlPgXGr2HlaN/view?usp=sharing